# How can I get specific dates from a number of weeks?

Tags: php, datetime

Using PHP, I'd like to get the dates for specific weekdays within a given number of weeks. For example, I want to get the dates for Monday, Wednesday and Friday from 10 weeks.

The pseudo code for what I want is like this:

```
function (monday, wednesday, friday, 10) {

    // 10 is week numbers

    week1 5,7,9 oct 2015
    week2  12,14,16 oct 2015 
    ...
    week10
}
```

---

i write a solution for this. Thanks for all answers.

```
<?
$dates = array();
$i = 0;

while(true) {
    $i++;

    $time = strtotime("+$i days");
    $dayOfWeek = date('w', $time);

    if(  
    /*
    0-sun
    1-mon***
    2-tue
    3-wed***
    4-thu
    5-fri***
    6-sat
    */
    ($dayOfWeek == 0) or
    ($dayOfWeek == 2) or
    ($dayOfWeek == 4) or 
    ($dayOfWeek == 6) 

      ) {
        continue;
    }

    $dates[] = date('Y-m-d', $time);

    if( count($dates) > 30 ) {
        break;
    }

    echo json_encode($dates ); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: So you haven't really tried anything, and expect to get work done for you?

Comment: Do you want 10 weeks relative to what date?

Comment: Also, please edit your question to add the code you've written trying to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Qirel what is your problem. I want to find a solution. Write a pseudo. get Stuck in a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to work with schedules. I suggest you to have a look at library called [When](https://github.com/tplaner/When), it's *"Date / Calendar recursion library for PHP 5.3+"*.

What you want to do is MWF schedule for next 10 weeks:

```
$now = new DateTime('NOW');
$after10Weeks = clone $now;
$after10Weeks->modify('+10 week');

$r = new When();
$r->startDate($now)
  ->freq("weekly")
  ->until($after10Weeks)
  ->byday(array('MO', 'WE', 'FR'))
  ->generateOccurrences();

$occurrences = $r->occurrences;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP DateTime **ISO date**:

```
$date = new DateTime(); //The object
$year=2015; // Desired year
$days = array('Mon', 'Wed', 'Fri'); // Desired days of week

for ($yearDay=1; $yearDay<=366; $yearDay++) {
    $date->setISODate($year,null, $yearDay); // call ISO Date
    $week=$date->format('W'); // Get the week resulted 
    $day=$date->format('D');  // Get the day name resulted

    if($week==10 && in_array($day, $days))  // return only dates of desired days of week 10
         echo $date->format('M d Y')."<br>";
}
```

More information about ISO Date [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php)

You can try this code with [PHPTester](http://phptester.net/)